# Show a line in the form $ax+by=c$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble with a question which states:

Point $M$ has coordinates $(3,5)$. Points $A$ and $B$ lie on the coordinate axes and have coordinates $(0,p)$ and $(q,0)$ so that $AMB$ is a right angle. Show that $5p+3q=34$.

Edit - solved:

I used the gradient  $\frac{p-5}{-3}$ $*$ $\frac{p-5}{-3}$ = -1
and multiplied the fractions together to give me $\frac{-5p+25}{-3q+9}$ = -1.
Then I cross-multiplied and got $-5p+25=3q-9$ and then rearranged the equation from there.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I tried supposing that p was equal to 5 and q was equal to 3 but then realised there were many different ways that you can make a right angle triangle based off a line.

Comment: Very nice that you have added a full solution. Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can proceed as follows

- the slope A-M is $$\frac{y_A-y_M}{x_A-x_M}=\frac{p-5}{-3}$$
- the slope B-M is $$\frac{y_B-y_M}{x_B-x_M}=\frac{-5}{q-3}$$

and we need

$$\frac{p-5}{-3}\cdot \frac{-5}{q-3}=-1$$

Comment: Thank you, solved the question!

Comment: @TheBeast Tha's fine! It should be nice if you can add your derivation editing your question with full details, for the benefit of future readers. Bye